# How can I store values from one array to another array using 'for' loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create number of arrays like _temp0[],_temp1[],_temp2[] so on and I want to store values of data[] in it.

so value of data[0] goes in array_temp0[] after splitting,

data[1] goes in _temp1[] and so on

to elaborate more-

If value of data[0] is string a,b,c

then array _temp0[] should be

```
_temp0[0]=a 
_temp0[1]=b 
_temp0[2]=c
```

I wrote this function

```
for(var k=0;k<data.length-1;k++)
{
    window['_temp' + k] = new Array();
    alert("actual data -- >"+data[k]);
    '_temp'+k= data[k].split(',');
    alert("data after split -- >"_temp[k]);
}
```

but it is not working, how do I solve it?

Comment: You also need nested loops to fill up the arrays.

Comment: Your code has at least one syntax error in it.

Comment: @go-oleg i know, it's at '_temp'+k= data[k].split(','); but i don't know how to resolve it

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do on that line.

Comment: @go-oleg trying to split value of data[0] and storing them in array _temp0

Comment: To do that you need to access it through the `window` object like you are doing earlier: `window['_temp'+k]`.  However, I don't recommend storing variables in the `window` object like this.

Comment: @go-oleg ok window['_temp'+k] worked perfectly, can you kindly mention that in an answer so i can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used

```
window['_temp'+k]= data[k].split(',');
```

instead of

```
'_temp'+k= data[k].split(',');
```

and it worked, thanks to go-oleg

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using javascript objects. Here is an example of how to do it.

Create an object of name '_temp':

```
var _temp = {};
```

When you iterate through 'data' variable then, you can dynamically add attributes to it,say _temp['data0'], _temp['data1'] etc, and every attribute will be an array. For that, you need to write something like:

```
for(var k=0;k<data.length-1;k++)
{
    _temp['data'+k] = data[k].split(',');
}
```

This will not create the variables identical to what you want. However, this is similar to what you want.